# How to remove initial wx.RadioBox selection?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have the following code :

```
myList =['a','b']
rb=wx.RadioBox(self.panel, -1, "Options :", (0, 0), wx.DefaultSize,myList, 2, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
```

When it renders first time I see that a choice has been made how can I change the code that when this radibox rendered first time there are no option has been chosen.

Answer (score 4):

The use of a [radio box](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html) implies, "there is a list of two or more options that are mutually exclusive and the user must select exactly one choice."

The radio box never exists in a state with no choice made. If that's not the case, then don't use a radio box.

If you don't want any of the current radio box options to be selected as default, 
add another option for "N/A" or "No choice".

Answer (score 2):

If your really need to do this then probably the only way is to create your own `RadioBox`. A `RadioBox` can easily built from a `Panel`, `StaticBox`, `StaticBoxSizer` and of course `RadioButtons`.

In the `__init__` for your RadioBox use the RadioButtons `SetValue()` method to set the initial value of the  `RadioButtons` to False.

Take a look at `RadioButton` demo in the wxpython Demos, there should be enough there to get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want initial selection invisible, you can have a try with ShowItem(item, show=True)

example here:

```
myList =['','a','b']
rb=wx.RadioBox(self.panel, -1, "Options :", (0, 0), wx.DefaultSize,myList, 2, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
rb.ShowItem(0, show=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Call the the radiobox SetSelection method with a parameter value of -1