# How to start a wxPython radiobox with no selection?

Tags: python, wxpython, radio-button, wxwidgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove initial wx.RadioBox selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691897/how-to-remove-initial-wx-radiobox-selection)

I'm working on an application that asks the user a series of questions with answers for each in a radiobox.  The next question does not appear until you have answered the current one because it may depend on your answer.

My problem is that each question that shows up automatically has the first answer selected by default.  I would like to have it start with nothing selected.

How can I achieve this?

Here's the code I'm currently using for one of the questions:

```
import wx

hardBackOptions = ['Paperback','Hardback'];


class OptionsPanel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        mainpanel = wx.Panel(self)


        self.cover1 = wx.RadioBox(self, label="Hardback or Paperback?",  pos=(20, 140), choices=hardBackOptions,  majorDimension=1, style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS )



app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Book Pricing & Options", size=(1000,900))
nb = wx.Notebook(frame)


nb.AddPage(OptionsPanel1(nb), "Book Options")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT:** For what it's worth, I ended up using wxChoice instead.  Having a blank option in front of the dropdown works better for what I was trying to accomplish than having a blank option for a radio button.  Here's the change I made for anyone interested:

```
import wx

hardBackOptions = ['','Paperback','Hardback'];


class OptionsPanel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        mainpanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.coverLabel = wx.StaticText(self, label="Paperback or Hardback?", pos=(20,115))
        self.cover = wx.Choice(self, pos=(20, 140), choices=hardBackOptions)



app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Book Pricing & Options", size=(1000,900))
nb = wx.Notebook(frame)


nb.AddPage(OptionsPanel1(nb), "Book Options")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: please post a short sample of code to demonstrate your example...

Comment: @Joran: Sorry, didn't include it initially because I assumed it would be a fairly straightforward question for someone with more experience than me with wxwidgets.  I have added the code for one of my questions now though.

Comment: It is certainly not overly dificuly however .. I want to be able to copy/paste hit run then fix your issue ... so post a complete example please :) (Including wx.App etc)

Comment: actually see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691897/wx-radiobox-python

Comment: Ah, I was expecting more of an explanation than for you to fix my code - so it makes more sense now why you requested the sample. Thanks for your patience!  I went ahead and updated the code sample, that should be more of what you're looking for.  

Based on the link you gave, it looks like the only way to do it is by not actually using the wx.RadioBox but by using RadioButton instead... Thanks for the help - somehow I was unable to find that when I was searching on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you're supposed to do that. Radio button sets should always have one value selected. I would just add a default value that's set such as one labeled "None".

Comment: It seems weird to me to require an option to be selected on a user input form before the user has done anything - but that may be the case with the RadioBox.

Regardless, having an option "None" or "N/A" or something similar doesn't really fit well with what I'm trying to do - which may simply mean I'm using the wrong tool for the job.  I may need to look into using wxChoice or wxListBox or something...